# Passion Distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Suppose the number of tsunami in a season follows a Poisson distribution and the average number of tsunami that hit a region is 5 in every tsunami season A tsunami season lasts for 3 months.

In the first month, 2 tsunamis occurred. Write an expression to evaluate the probability that in total, there will be more than 5 tsunami this season, 3 months.

Comment: Hi. You should read the FAQ on how to ask questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to add the 'self-study' tag to the question. Also, you need to write down what you have tried so far and/or make it more clear where you are stuck. What keeps you from starting the task? Do you know what the Poisson distribution is?